# OSX Terminal: how to add same item to each line of a csv file?

Tags: linux, csv, command-line, terminal

I have got a csv file like this:

```
120,256,300
36,255,12
etc...
```

I want to add a fixed string like 'USA' to all lines in order to obtain:

```
120,256,300,USA
36,255,12,USA
etc...
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a text processing point of view that CSV file is plain text in this context, you just want to attach `, USA` to each line.

The easiest (and operationally least expensive) way to do so is probably:

```
sed -i '' 's/$/, USA/' file
```

What this does is to instruct sed to look for the *end of line* `$` and "replace" it with `, USA`.  As `sed` is line-based this obviously doesn't actually trim out the new line of the file.

`-i ''` instructs `sed` to make the changes in-line without creating a backup file.

If you wanted a backup you can put the desired extension instead of `''`, e.g. `-i .bak`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `sed`: `cat <input-file> | sed 's/\(.*\)/\1, USA/'`.

Here `s` is the substitute command, which uses the following character as a separator between a regular expression and a substitution.  For the regular expression, the escaped parenthesis are used to create a capture group, the regex `.*` captures the entire line. For the substitution, the `\1` inserts the first capture group, and then the `, USA` text is appended.

You can perform the replacement in place using: `sed -i .bak 's/\(.*\)/\1, USA/' <input-file>`

Comment: Or even shorter `sed 's/$/, USA/' file` ... really no need to capture the entire line.

Comment: True, but that wouldn't have allowed me to explain capture groups and back references.

Comment: Heh. A bit like explaining the merits of a stroll along the esplanade to someone who asked for the way to the bus stop =}